# Angular JS - Passing ng-click $index value to a controller function then back to another view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am pass the ng-click $index value to my controller then using it's value in an ng-repeat to my data from an array but getting an error suggesting "ReferenceError: myChoice is not defined"

My view (months.html) has a list of all the months, when selected, it passes value to the controller.

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="time in times.months" ng-click="getMonthId($index)" style="">
  <ion-item style="" href="#/dmtimes">{{ time.monthId }} - {{ time.MonthName }</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The view output is shows:

```
1 - Jan
2 - Feb 
3 - Mar
etc
```

My controller has the following extract code:

```
.controller('dailyMeetingTimesCtrl', function($scope, MeetingNames, $ionicLoading, $firebase, $firebaseArray) {

  $scope.getMonthId = function (monthId) {
    alert("you selected: " + monthId); // this works fine.
    $scope.myChoice = monthId; // ReferenceError: myChoice is not defined

    console.log(myChoice);
  }
})
```

In my second view (displayMeetingTimes.html) I want to display the meeting details, times etc for the selected month. The code is as follows:

```
<ion-view title="Daily Meeting Times">
  <ion-content ng-controller="dailyMeetingTimesCtrl" class="has-header" overflow-scroll="true" padding="true">
    <ion-list>

      <ion-item ng-repeat="time in times.months(myChoice).days" class="item-text-wrap">
        <span>{{myChoice}}</span>
        Meeting Name:   {{ time.meetingName }}<br />
        Star Time:  {{ time.startTime }}<br />
        Finish Time:    {{ time.finishTime }}<br />
      </ion-item>         
    </ion-list>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

When I ran the application, the value of 'myChoice' is not passing through to the second view hence the error "ReferenceError: myChoice is not defined"

Please advise where I'm going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: should be `console.log($scope.myChoice);`, no?

Comment: Thank you, console.log($scope.myChoice); now works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to pass the `$index` using `ng-repeat`, you need to specify it. So your HTML should be like following:

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="time in times.months track by $index" ng-click="getMonthId($index)" style="">
  <ion-item style="" href="#/dmtimes">{{ time.monthId }} - {{ time.MonthName }
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Secondly, the reason why you are getting `ReferenceError: myChoice is not defined`is because you have never initialized a variable called `myChoice`. However you do have a variable called `$scope.myChoice`.

Therefore, you should do the following for display the variable in the console:

```
console.log($scope.myChoice);
```

Comment: Thank you...I've made the changes to the HTMl as suggested but in my second HTML file, how do I read the myChoice value? I.e. <ion-item ng-repeat="time in times.months($scope.myChoice).days" class="item-text-wrap"> doesn't work...

Comment: `<ion-item ng-repeat="time in times.months(myChoice).days" class="item-text-wrap">` Don't put `$scope` in the view. When you access `$scope` variable, you don't put `$scope` in the html.

Comment: I've already tried that, I get an error: "TypeError: v12.months is not a function" which doesn't make much sense to me. Do you know why? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have different controllers for different views? I need more information to help you.

Comment: I don't have 20 reputation on SO to discuss.  One controller for both views: `.controller('dailyMeetingTimesCtrl', function($scope, MeetingNames, $ionicLoading, $firebase, $firebaseArray) {
  
 $scope.getMonthId = function (monthId) {
  alert("you selected: " + monthId);
  $scope.myChoice = monthId;
  
  console.log(myChoice);
  
 }
})
`

Comment: Both views call the _dailyMeetingTimesCtrl_ controller

Comment: Since I have fixed the error `ReferenceError: myChoice is not defined` and display the variable in `$scope.myChoice`. Please consider accept the answer. And for the second question, please make a new post with updated code, so that people can target specific problem to help you.