# Angular js - "TypeError: v12.months is not a function"

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

This question is ongoing/ related to my [first original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635306/angular-js-passing-ng-click-index-value-to-a-controller-function-then-back-to?answertab=active#tab-top).

I have one controller (dailyMeetingTimesCtrl) for both views:

```
.controller('dailyMeetingTimesCtrl', function($scope, MeetingNames,$ionicLoading, $firebase, $firebaseArray) { 
    $scope.getMonthId = function (monthId) { 
        alert("you selected: " + monthId); 
        $scope.myChoice = monthId; 
        console.log(myChoice); 
     }
 })
```

I can `console.log` the value of `myChoice` variable but when using it as `<ion-item ng-repeat="time in times.months(myChoice).days" class="item-text-wrap">` or {{myChoice}} in the view, I get the error "TypeError: v12.months is not a function".

I'm not sure what errors means, please advice. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the data of `times`?

Comment: Its: as follows: `{
 "months": [{
  "MonthName": "January",
  "days": [{
   "meetingDate": "01 - January",
   "meetingName": "4:35",
   "meetingDesc": "5:50",
   "startTime": ""
  }, {
   "meetingDate": "02 - January",
   "meetingName": "4:35",
   "meetingDesc": "5:50",
   "startTime": ""
  }]
 }, {
  "MonthName": "February",
  "days": [{
   "meetingDate": "01 - February",
   "meetingName": "4:35",
   "meetingDesc": "5:50",
   "startTime": "",
   "startFinish": "5:30"
  }, {
   "meetingDate": "02 - February",
   "meetingName": "4:35",
   "meetingDesc": "5:50",
   "startTime": ""
  }]
 }]
}`

Comment: If I update the code to: `<ion-item ng-repeat="time in times.months[1].days" class="item-text-wrap">` it works fine but for some reason its doesn't like (myChoice). Thanks Shaohao.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `myChoice` is not working is because that is not the correct way to access the element of an array.
Instead of doing this:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="time in times.months(myChoice).days" class="item-text-wrap">
```

You should change to

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="time in times.months[myChoice].days" class="item-text-wrap">
```

[Working Demo for your approach](http://codepen.io/shaohaolin/pen/zrwGYL).

You can actually pass the selected month instead of just the array, which you don't have to do `times.months[1].days` anymore.

#### Method 2:

Instead of passing the **id** of the month, you can pass the selected month.

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="month in times.months track by $index" ng-click="getMonth(month, $index)">
  <ion-item href="#/dmtimes">{{ month.monthId }} - {{ month.MonthName }
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.getMonth = function (month, monthId) {
    alert("you selected: " + monthId);
    console.log(month);
    $scope.selectedMonth = month;
}
```

View 2:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="time in selectedMonth.days" class="item-text-wrap">
    <span>{{selectedMonth.MonthName}}</span>
    Meeting Name:   {{ time.meetingName }}<br />
    Star Time:  {{ time.startTime }}<br />
    Finish Time:    {{ time.finishTime }}<br />
  </ion-item>         
</ion-list>
```

I have made a **Updated** [Working Demo](http://codepen.io/shaohaolin/pen/xZqvWz) for method 2 approach.

Comment: I went with method 2, made more sense moving forward. However, the alert in the controller outputs "you selected: [object Object]" and not the selected month id. Therefore, view 2 isn't displaying the data but I can see the results in console.log for `console.log($scope.selectedMonth);` I really appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: If you really want to get the `monthId`, you can pass the `$index` through the `ng-click` function. I have made an update for the method 2 demo and on the post. If my answer works for you, please consider upvote  and/or accept it. Thank you. It is good for the community.

Comment: Awesome - Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. You know you can upvote the answer as well, which helps to display in priority.

Comment: I did that for your questions but don't have enough reputation. I see this message: "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score". Thanks

Comment: Oh Thank you. But why you don't accept this answer anymore? You can still accept the answer even you don't have 15 reputation.

Comment: I did accept the answer, not sure why it got unaccepted. Maybe my mistake...I have accepted it again. Many thanks.